# Angular: Delete 2 different models together

Tags: angular

I have a form with FullName, userName password.
These are my models:

```
export interface Contact{
    id:string,
    displayName:string,
    status:boolean,
    userId: string
}

export interface User{
    id:string,
    userName:string,
    password:string
}
```

As you can see the model of the User belongs to the name and password and the FullName belongs to the contact.

I want to delete both but I have one problem I associate the URL with the user id and he does not know the name.

here:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(
  params =>{
    const id = params.get('id');
    if(id){
      this.usersService.GetUserById(id)
      .subscribe(
        response =>{
          this.user = response;
        }
      )
    }
  }
)
```

I can not find a better solution I will present my code here:

HttpClient Delete (user & contact):

```
DeleteUser(id: string):Observable<User>{
    return this.http.delete<User>(this.baseUrl + this.usersUrl + '/' + id)
  }

DeleteContact(id: string):Observable<Contact>{
    return this.http.delete<Contact>(this.baseUrl + this.ContactsUrl + '/' + id)
  }
```

When I try to delete only the user is deleted:

```
deleteUser(userId:string){

    this.usersService.DeleteUser(userId)
    .subscribe(() =>{
      this.contactService.DeleteContact(userId)
      .subscribe(()=>{
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        })
      })
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm, not understand the problem. So currently based on the last code snippet, you are able to delete the user but unable to delete contact in sequence? *I want to delete both but I have one problem I associate the URL with the user id and he does not know the name.*

Comment: Yes I can not delete the contact because they are from different tables

Comment: So the inner observable for `DeleteContact` is unable to trigger and send request to API? Need to clarify which part meets the issue, either front-end side or back-end side.

Comment: A suggestion: Have you considered implementing the API that removes User and Contact together? Although you have the `Contact` and `User` tables separately, but the main data that you need to delete the record is `userId`, so I believe that it is possible to implement it into one method (API). While the Angular side you just need to call the API for once (without a nested API call). But it depends on will you able to modify the API services.

Comment: I will fix myself the API works fine but because I send it to the url of the user id: **http: // localhost: 4200 / contact? Id = b091a254-623f-462e-a620-5667785830f4**
And he here does not know the contact understand?

Comment: Good idea My question is if in micro service it can hurt if I do it in such a method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246428/discussion-between-yong-shun-and-tommy-udi).